# relation between two dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdownlist,when i select an option from first one,related options show in second dropdown.i have used jquery but i dont know why it doesent work.
this is cshtml page:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductSubGroup.ProductGroupID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProductGroupID", (SelectList)ViewBag.Type, "-- انتخاب ---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",id = "rdbGroup" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductSubGroup.ProductGroupID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductSubGroupID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProductSubGroupID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ProductSubGroupID, "-- انتخاب ---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",id = "rdbSubGroup" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductSubGroupID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is controller

```
public ActionResult SelectCategory(int id)
 {
     var categoris = db.ProductSubGroup.Where(m => m.ProductGroup.ProductGroupID == id).Select(c => new { c.ProductSubGroupID, c.ProductSubGroupTitle});
     return Json(categoris, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }

 // GET: Admin/Products/Create
 public ActionResult Create()
 {

     ViewBag.ProductGroupID=new SelectList(db.ProductGroup,"ProductGroupID","Produ  ctGroupTitle");
     ViewBag.ProductSubGroupID = new SelectList(db.ProductSubGroup, "ProductSubGroupID", "ProductSubGroupTitle");


         return View();
 }
```

and this is javascript

```
  $('#rdbGroup').change(function () {
                jQuery.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectCategory")', { id: $(this).attr('value') }, function (data) {
                    $('#rdbSubGroup').empty();
                    jQuery.each(data, function (i) {
                        var option = $('<option></option>').attr("value", data[i].Id).text(data[i].Title);
                        $("#rdbSubGroup").append(option);
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: What is not working? Is your script being executed? Are your hitting the controller? What errors are you getting?

Comment: why not using `$(this).val()` instead of `attr('value')`

Comment: it gives me no error,but when i select a group there is no change on the other dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a sample of mine

**cs.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FakulteId, "Fakülte", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FakulteId, ViewBag.Fakulte as SelectList, "Fakülte Seçiniz", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "fakulteSec", @onchange = "secim()" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BolumId, "Bölüm", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BolumId, ViewBag.Bolum as SelectList, "Bölüm Seçiniz", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "bolum" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

**controller**

```
public JsonResult FakulteBolumDrop(int id)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Bolum> bolum = db.Bolum.Where(b => b.FakulteId == id).ToList();
        return Json(bolum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**.js**

```
function secim() {
        var fakulteId = $('#fakulteSec').val();
        //alert(fakulteId);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Rektor/FakulteBolumDrop?id=' + fakulteId,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { Fakulte: fakulteId },
            success: function (bolumler) {
                $("#bolum").html("");
                $.each(bolumler, function (i, bolum) {
                    $("#bolum").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(bolum.BolumId).html(bolum.Adi));
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you know about 3 related dropdown?

Comment: I did not do it before.Can be done in the same way.add onchange to second dropdownlist

Comment: one little problem happend,when i use it for 3 dropdown,when i select an item from first dropdown,second dropdown items come true,while third one show all items,not dependant items on second dropdown,and i should change items on second,even i want to have firest item in second dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your change event of  rdbGroup Drop Down inside the

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  });
```

Otherwise it will not be fired.

Comment: Not necessarily - the script might be at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`.

Try

```
 $('#rdbGroup').on('change',function () {// or $(document).on('change', '#rdbGroup',function (){
      $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SelectCategory")', { id: this.value }, function (data) {
       $('#rdbSubGroup').empty();
       $.each(data, function (i,item) {// if data is json string form the replace data by $.parseJSON(data)
          //console.log(item.Id); console.log(item.Title);
          $('#rdbSubGroup').append($('<option>', { 
               value:item.Id,
               text :item.Title 
        })); //OR you can use --- $('#rdbSubGroup').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item.Id).text(item.Title)); 
         });
      });
    });
```

**OR**

```
$('#rdbGroup').on('change',function () {// or $(document).on('change', '#rdbGroup',function (){
   var id= this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SelectCategory")',
        data: { 
            id: id
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#rdbSubGroup").html("");           
        $.each(data, function (i,item) {         
            $('#rdbSubGroup').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",item.Id).text(item.Title)); 
            //OR $('#rdbSubGroup').append($('<option>', { value:item.Id, text :item.Title}));    
          });
       });        
    });
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply,i have done what you said,but when i select a group,second dropdown show me nothing,and its blank

Comment: @Mansoure i update my answer a lite bit. uncomment `//console.log(item.Id); console.log(item.Title);` and insure this log valid data in browser developer tool console.

Comment: when i set breakpoint on selectcategory function ,informations are correct,just dosent show in second dropdown,and it shows blank

Comment: @Mansoure please try the alternative option for adding option in dropdown

Comment: I am new,would youe plz guide me?

Comment: @Mansoure please try alternative option